# Application Ito's formula

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

## Question

We have a stochastic process $(X_t)_t$ that can be written by:
$$
dX_t = -\mu dt - \sigma dB_t + d\nu_t,
$$
with $(B_t)_t$ a standard brownian motion and $d\nu_t$ equal to some number $\xi_t$ at some finite number of times $\eta_t$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $V$ be an arbitrary function then we want to apply Ito's formula to the expression:
$$
V(x) - \mathbb{E}\left[ V(X_{\Delta t}) e^{-\alpha\Delta t } \right]
$$
to obtain that this expression is equal to
$$
\Delta t \left( -\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{d^2V}{dx^2} + \mu \frac{dV}{dx} + \alpha V \right)
$$
or at least that's what I think has to be shown.

## Origin Of The Question

At the top of page 309 of [Inventory Management With Stochastic Lead Times](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/moor.2014.0671) Ito's formula is used but I don't understand this step.